# IBM Mobilefirst Javascript Client-side API WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated returns true even if session is expired

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

```
mfp version 7.1.0.00.20151227-1730
```

- In login module set `expirationInSeconds` to 20 seconds.
- Login and wait for 20 seconds.
- Session expires.
- When I try to access protected resources it responds correct (asks for authentication).
- But..`WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("realmName")` still returns true (!).

Seems that this function just returns cached boolean, and not true status.

How do I check real auth status?

Comment: Do you use `invokeProcedure` or `WLResourceRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

When using `WLResourceRequest` you automatically use the new **OAuth** framework for authentication.

The `WLClient` APIs are not relevant in the OAuth flow. Instead, you should look at the `WLAuthorizationManager` APIs: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLAuthorizationManager.html

Comment: Im using classic authentication model. Not OAuth. Now I use workaround with request to protected dummy resource. If server asks for auth - Im not logged in

Comment: In the question I asked if you use `WLResourceRequest` or `invokeProcedure`, and you answered `WLResourceRequest`. Is this still true?

Comment: Yes. I use WLResourceRequest since it is much comfortable, but our project is built on classic authentication system with realms and login modules.

Comment: `WLResourceRequest` **only** supports OAuth. As soon as you use `WLResourceRequest`, the framework automatically switches you over to OAuth silently. It converts all of your "classic" stuff to "OAuth" stuff. Welcome to OAuth :)